# SQL Server - List single row multiple times in query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a dataset in a SQL Server database, and I'd like to list run a query to list records from a table, multiple times according to the respective integer value in a column of that table.

I've seen many of the posts about listing a record multiple times in a query, with most of the more suitable responses describing a solution involving Cross join. The situation I'm describing is slightly different from what I've seen of yet, however.

The table structure of the records is akin to the following:

```
+-----+-------+------+------+
| id  | name  | type | num  |
+-----+-------+------+------+
| 1   | bob   | red  | 1    |
+-----+-------+------+------+
| 2   | sam   | blue | 3    |
+-----+-------+------+------+
| 3   | viv   | green| 2    |
+-----+-------+------+------+
```

I'd like to display this in a query result as follows...

```
+-----+-------+------+
| id  | name  | type |
+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | bob   | red  |
+-----+-------+------+
| 2   | sam   | blue |
+-----+-------+------+
| 2   | sam   | blue |
+-----+-------+------+
| 2   | sam   | blue |
+-----+-------+------+
| 3   | viv   | green|
+-----+-------+------+
| 3   | viv   | green|
+-----+-------+------+
```

... where each record appears multiple times according to the number it is listed in the original row. (bob * 1, sam * 3, viv * 2)

Is this possible via cross-join or any other method available?

---

***Note:*** This does not need to be terribly efficient.

Comment: Look for recursive CTE

Comment: The simplest answer is to create a numbers table.  Then you join on to that `data JOIN numbers ON numbers.id BETWEEN 1 AND data.num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use  `recursive CTE`

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT id,name,type,1 startnum,num    
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,name,type , startnum+1,num    
    FROM cte
    WHERE startnum+1<=num
)

SELECT id,name,type
FROM cte
order by id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c6266accfe98aa550d2402242585192a)

Comment: Thanks! This was simple enough to do the trick, and easy enough to modify for my actual case. eg. I wanted records to display once if `num=0`, so I set `0 as startnum` in the first part of the `WITH` clause. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is an ad-hoc tally/numbers table

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.[Name]
      ,A.[Type]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Top (A.[num]) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1) B
```

**Or a simple JOIN**

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.[Name]
      ,A.[Type]
 From YourTable A
 Join (Select Top (100) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1) B
   on B.N<=A.[Num]
```

**Both would Return**

```
ID  Name    Type
1   bob     red
2   sam     blue
2   sam     blue
2   sam     blue
3   viv     green
3   viv     green
```

Comment: @MatBailie I'd suspect the Join is a nudge faster, but the Cross Apply allows for a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Stored procedure 
create a temporary table variable
Write insert into temporary table in a while loop
while counter < max(num)
insert into table  where counter <=num

Finally select from table .

Comment: SP's and loops are a final fall back position, not a first option.

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED:

(Thanks, @MatBailie!)

Using a recursive CTE on the `num` column to generate the required number of repetitions, and doing a left-join:

Given table `so1` as follows:

```
   id   name   type    num
    1   bob    red      1
    2   sam    blue     3
    3   viv    green    2
    4   jon    grey     7
```

Try:

```
WITH RECURSIVE exp_num AS
(
SELECT id, num FROM so1
UNION
SELECT id, num - 1 FROM exp_num WHERE num > 1
)

SELECT s1.* FROM so1 s1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT id FROM exp_num
) s2
ON s1.id = s2.id
```

Output:

```
id  name  type
1   bob   red 
2   sam   blue      
2   sam   blue      
2   sam   blue      
3   viv   green     
3   viv   green     
4   jon   grey      
4   jon   grey      
4   jon   grey      
4   jon   grey     
4   jon   grey      
4   jon   grey      
4   jon   grey
```

Comment: Assumes that `a).` All the ID's in `sol` are contiguous *(no gaps)* `b).` That the lowest `id` is 1 and the highest `id` is greater than or equal to the highest `num`.

Comment: It's also not a cross join.  It's a LEFT JOIN, you typed that in your SQL yourself.  Maybe you meant a "self-join"?

Comment: For knowledge purposes, what's the reason for the left join, if the recursive CTE already duplicates the records? Thanks!